# How did the Marriott block wifi hotspots?

Tags: wireless-networking, blocking

As per this article in CNN: [Marriott fined $600,000 by FCC for blocking guests' Wi-Fi](http://www.cnn.com/2014/10/03/travel/marriott-fcc-wi-fi-fine/)

How is it possible to do what's described in this article?  It's saying that they were able to block personal wifi hotspots while still allowing people to access only their wifi access points.  It also says they weren't "jamming" (I can't see how you could jam and also allow access to your own access points).  Another article covering the same story said you just couldn't even "see" your own wifi hotspots.

EDIT:
The [FCC release](http://www.fcc.gov/document/marriott-pay-600k-resolve-wifi-blocking-investigation) says "The FCC Enforcement Bureau’s investigation revealed that Marriott employees had used containment features of a Wi-Fi monitoring system at the Gaylord Opryland to prevent individuals from connecting to the Internet via their own personal Wi-Fi networks".  It also seems to indicate they did it with packet injection to cause disconnections (is that possible when using encryption?  Or does that get done before the connection can go into encryption?)

Comment: You engineer a denial-of-service against any wifi hotspot that you don't know about, likely using a de-auth flood.

Comment: It's really too broad of a question to be good for anywhere in StackExchange. Layer 1 jamming would be the most effective, but would mean that other hotspots sharing the channel your APs use would have to be left alone and you'd still have considerable cross-channel interference from the jammers. Spoofing deauth packets would let you target same-channel hotpots without significantly impacting your own, but I'm not sure how it would keep users from being able to see their own hotspots - certainly, they might not be able to join them but they should still be able to see them.

Comment: @Iszi - I think that article must have been wrong about "not seeing" hotspots.  The deauth packet injection seems to be what happened based on the FCC release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the FCC release further it says:

> Marriott operates a Wi-Fi monitoring system manufactured by a third
>   party that was installed at the Gaylord Opryland. Among other
>   features, the system includes a containment capability that, when
>   activated, will cause the sending of de-authentication packets to
>   Wi-Fi Internet access points that are not part of Marriott’s Wi-Fi
>   system or authorized by Marriott and that Marriott has classified as
>   “rogue.”

A [Wi-Fi Deauthentication Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_deauthentication_attack) uses a feature of the IEEE 802.11 protocol called a deauthentication frame which is a ["sanctioned technique to inform a rogue station that they have been disconnected from the network"](http://www.willhackforsushi.com/papers/wlan-sess-cont.pdf).

An attacker can send a deauthentication frame at any time to a wireless access point, with a spoofed address for the victim. The protocol does not require any encryption for this frame and the attacker only needs to know the victim's MAC address, which is available in the clear.

A good article on how to do this is [Forcing a device to disconnect from WiFi using a deauthentication attack](https://skerritt.blog/forcing-a-device-to-disconnect-from-wifi-using-a-deauthentication-attack/)

Note that this is prevented by the new [Protected Management Frames (PMF)](https://www.wi-fi.org/knowledge-center/faq/what-are-protected-management-frames) feature of WPA2 and WPA3, also known as [IEEE 802.11w-2009](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11w-2009).

Answer (score 2):

The Gaylord Opryland Resort operated APs which would send 802.11 deauthentication frames with spoofed addresses, basically fooling client devices into thinking that they were disconnected from the Wi-Fi network. This attack only requires the target device's MAC address, which is trivial to obtain through monitoring of wireless network activity, and is independent of any encryption. This is called a [deauthentication attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_deauthentication_attack).

Marriott was ultimately fined $600,000 when the FCC ruled this operation to be illegal jamming. The deauthentication attacks interfered with lawful wireless communications, even though it did not involve the usual approach of emitting noise to disrupt communication.